# Etat HTTP 500 - java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'command' available as request attribute

Tags: java, xml, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I am getting this error in my spring mvc web app when trying to edit or create a **"Carrosserie"**

> Etat HTTP 500 - java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'command'
>   available as request attribute

I have seen my people asked this question before. I have gone through the answers but nothing's working for me. I have no bean named 'command' in my models class.
Please help me. Thanks in advance

**This my controller**

```
package com.controller;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

import org.jboss.logging.Logger;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import com.model.Carrosserie;
import com.service.CarrosserieService;

@Controller
public class CarrosserieController {

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(CarrosserieController.class);

    public CarrosserieController() {
        System.out.println("CarrosserieController");
    }

    @Autowired
    private CarrosserieService service;

    @RequestMapping(value="/newCarrosserie", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView newCarrosserie(ModelAndView model){
        Carrosserie carrosserie = new Carrosserie();
        System.out.println(carrosserie);
        model.addObject("carrosserie", carrosserie);
        model.setViewName("newcarrosserieform");
        return model;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/savecarrosserie", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView saveCarrosserie(@ModelAttribute Carrosserie carrosserie){

        if(carrosserie.getIdCarrosserie() == 0) {
            service.addCarrosserie(carrosserie);
        }else {
            service.updateCarrosserie(carrosserie);
        }

        return new ModelAndView("redirect:/listcarrosserie");
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/listcarrosserie", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView listCarrosserie(ModelAndView model) throws IOException{
        List<Carrosserie> listCarrosserie = service.getAllCarrosserie();
        model.addObject("listCarrosserie", listCarrosserie);
        model.setViewName("listcarrosserie");
        return model;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/editCarrosserie", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView editCarrosserie(HttpServletRequest request){
        Carrosserie carrosserie = service.getCarrosserieById(Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("idCarrosserie")));
        System.out.println(carrosserie);
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("newcarrosserieform");
        model.addObject("carrosserie", carrosserie);        
        return model;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/deletecarrosserie", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView deleteCarrosserie(HttpServletRequest request){
        service.deleteCarrosserie(Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("idCarrosserie")));
        return new ModelAndView("redirect:/listcarrosserie");
    }
}
```

**This my newcarrosserieform.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>

<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
            <title>Nouvelle carrosserie</title>
        </head>
    <body>

        <h1>Ajout / MAJ Carrosserie</h1>

        <div align="center">
            <form:form action="saveCarrosserie" method="post" modelAttribut="carrosserie">
                <table>
                    <form:hidden path="idCarrosserie"/>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Libellé</td>
                        <td><form:input path="libelleCarrosserie"/></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" value="Enregistrer"/></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </form:form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**This is my spring-servlet.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com"/>
    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:application.properties"/>
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>
    <mvc:resources location="/ressources/" mapping="/resources/**"/>
    <mvc:resources location="/ressources/css/" mapping="/resources/css/**"/>

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/views/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${database.driver}"/>
        <property name="url" value="${database.url}"/>
        <property name="username" value="${database.username}"/>
        <property name="password" value="${database.password}"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_format">${hibernate.show_format}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.model"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

</beans>
```

**Trace**

```
oct. 09, 2017 11:12:23 AM org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.HiddenInputTag doStartTag
GRAVE: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'command' available as request attribute
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'command' available as request attribute
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus.<init>(BindStatus.java:144)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getBindStatus(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:168)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getPropertyPath(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:188)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getName(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:154)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.autogenerateId(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:141)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.resolveId(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:132)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.writeDefaultAttributes(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:116)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractHtmlElementTag.writeDefaultAttributes(AbstractHtmlElementTag.java:422)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.HiddenInputTag.writeTagContent(HiddenInputTag.java:79)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractFormTag.doStartTagInternal(AbstractFormTag.java:84)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.RequestContextAwareTag.doStartTag(RequestContextAwareTag.java:80)
    at org.apache.jsp.views.newcarrosserieform_jsp._jspx_meth_form_005fhidden_005f0(newcarrosserieform_jsp.java:204)
    at org.apache.jsp.views.newcarrosserieform_jsp._jspx_meth_form_005fform_005f0(newcarrosserieform_jsp.java:155)
    at org.apache.jsp.views.newcarrosserieform_jsp._jspService(newcarrosserieform_jsp.java:107)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:439)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:747)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:485)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:410)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:337)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:168)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:303)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1228)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1011)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:955)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:877)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:857)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:624)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:218)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:958)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:452)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1087)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:318)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

oct. 09, 2017 11:12:23 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher invoke
GRAVE: "Servlet.service()" pour la servlet jsp a lancé une exception
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'command' available as request attribute
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus.<init>(BindStatus.java:144)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getBindStatus(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:168)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getPropertyPath(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:188)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getName(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:154)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.autogenerateId(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:141)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.resolveId(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:132)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.writeDefaultAttributes(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:116)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractHtmlElementTag.writeDefaultAttributes(AbstractHtmlElementTag.java:422)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.HiddenInputTag.writeTagContent(HiddenInputTag.java:79)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractFormTag.doStartTagInternal(AbstractFormTag.java:84)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.RequestContextAwareTag.doStartTag(RequestContextAwareTag.java:80)
    at org.apache.jsp.views.newcarrosserieform_jsp._jspx_meth_form_005fhidden_005f0(newcarrosserieform_jsp.java:204)
    at org.apache.jsp.views.newcarrosserieform_jsp._jspx_meth_form_005fform_005f0(newcarrosserieform_jsp.java:155)
    at org.apache.jsp.views.newcarrosserieform_jsp._jspService(newcarrosserieform_jsp.java:107)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:439)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:747)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:485)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:410)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:337)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:168)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:303)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1228)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1011)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:955)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:877)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:857)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:624)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:218)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:958)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:452)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1087)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:318)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

oct. 09, 2017 11:12:23 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
GRAVE: Servlet.service() for servlet [spring] in context with path [/spring_gestionobjetsvolesouperdus_webapp] threw exception [An exception occurred processing JSP page /views/newcarrosserieform.jsp at line 17

14:         <div align="center">
15:             <form:form action="saveCarrosserie" method="post" modelAttribut="carrosserie">
16:                 <table>
17:                     <form:hidden path="idCarrosserie"/>
18:                     <tr>
19:                         <td>Libellé</td>
20:                         <td><form:input path="libelleCarrosserie"/></td>


Stacktrace:] with root cause
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'command' available as request attribute
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus.<init>(BindStatus.java:144)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getBindStatus(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:168)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getPropertyPath(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:188)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getName(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:154)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.autogenerateId(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:141)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.resolveId(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:132)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.writeDefaultAttributes(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:116)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractHtmlElementTag.writeDefaultAttributes(AbstractHtmlElementTag.java:422)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.HiddenInputTag.writeTagContent(HiddenInputTag.java:79)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractFormTag.doStartTagInternal(AbstractFormTag.java:84)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.RequestContextAwareTag.doStartTag(RequestContextAwareTag.java:80)
    at org.apache.jsp.views.newcarrosserieform_jsp._jspx_meth_form_005fhidden_005f0(newcarrosserieform_jsp.java:204)
    at org.apache.jsp.views.newcarrosserieform_jsp._jspx_meth_form_005fform_005f0(newcarrosserieform_jsp.java:155)
    at org.apache.jsp.views.newcarrosserieform_jsp._jspService(newcarrosserieform_jsp.java:107)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:439)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:747)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:485)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:410)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:337)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:168)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:303)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1228)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1011)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:955)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:877)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:857)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:624)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:218)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:958)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:452)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1087)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:318)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally found what's wrong. I should write modelAttribute with "e" at the end instead of modelAttribut in my jsp

```
<form:form action="saveCarrosserie" method="post" modelAttribut="carrosserie">
```

Thanks a lot for those who tried to help